# XML file save, potential security issues?

Tags: php, xml, security, magento, file-io

I'm creating a Magento module that saves user-input data to an xml file (held on the server for later use - think business card orders). I'm wondering how secure my process is, and what (if any) security issues might come up. I'll note that I'm hosting this site with a company that specializes in pci-compliant servers and is, additionally, running under `CHROOT`.

I have some legacy flash files that do the entry (there's a number of them, or I'd just recreate them). These are printing orders, so they need to accept all manner of special characters (and thus, doesn't do too much in the way of validation).

From there: 
$.ajax -> processor.php ->

```
    /* grab params */
    if (isset($_POST)) {
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
            $params[$key] = filter_var($value, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        }
    }

    /* build xml */
    $xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
    $xml_root = $xml->createElement('Root');
    foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
        $xml_node = $xml->createElement( $key );
        if(!empty($value) && $value != 'undefined'){
            $xml_node->appendChild( $xml->createTextNode( $value ));
        }
        $xml_root->appendChild($xml_node);
    }
    $xml->appendChild($xml_root);

    /* create filename */
    $d = new DateTime('now');
    $date = str_replace(" ", ".",$d->format('Y-m-d G:i:s'));
    $keyvar = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9-]/', '', $params['keyVar']);
    $filename = str_replace(" ", "", $params['template'].".".$date.".".$keyvar.".xml" );
    $file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/media/customer/orders/'.$filename;

    /* write it */
    $xml->save($file);
```

Then I just pass a reference of the file (but not the location) back to the client to be attached to the order.

So: no includes; vars are sanitized (still allowing for special characters); unique file name; file saved to unknown location (via the front-end).

The system is going to be scrutinized by IT security, I just want to catch anything prior to that review.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: may be save that files out of documnet_root, or that location should be at least not browsable

Comment: This code is vulnerable to directory traversal,  use a database or something.

Comment: Where does `$filename` come from?

Comment: the file name is being concatenated from the type of product it is (its template), a date stamp, and a human readable identifier (the keyvar.

Comment: I think saving the file outside of the doc root would be easy to implement. I think I can test for "../" also to protect against directory traversal. As noted - the server is set up as a chroot jail, so I didn't think it would be an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saving outside the servable files is a good idea, and easy to implement.
Also - final check for directory traversal prior to saving...

```
$path = '/home/user/orders/printing/';
$file = $path.$filename;

if ( !preg_match("../", $file) ){
    /* write it */
    $xml->save($file);
}
```